# Why does np.sqrt(1-0.5**2) not return 0.75 as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sqrt

Consider the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.sqrt(1 - 0.5**2))
```

This returns a long decimal beginning with 0.86, whereas I would expect it to return 0.75.  Why the discrepancy?

Comment: What do you mean? `1 - 0.5**2 == 0.75` and `sqrt(0.75) != 0.75`

Comment: @ForceBru Sorry Forcey, I lost my mind for a bit.

Comment: sqrt is an abbrevation of square root, your result is the square root of 0.75.

Comment: @ipaleka Thanks ipy, somewhere along the way my brain short circuited.  But I am on the road to recovery.

Comment: @layman, no problem, layboi! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step by step, one that happens:

```
import numpy as np

exp = (0.5**2)

print(exp)

diff = 1 - exp

print(diff)

print(np.sqrt(diff))
```

Comment: Thank you, Damian.  I am slowly regaining my sanity.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you're expecting it to return 0.75. Consider in detail what you're doing:

```
1 - 0.5**2
```

Square `0.5`, and then subtract that from 1. This yields 0.75, as expected.

```
np.sqrt(1 - 0.5**2)
np.sqrt(0.75)
```

Now, `numpy` takes the square root of 0.75, and returns `0.8660254037844386`. As it should, because that's the square root of 0.75.

Answer (score 1):

Because `1-0.5**2` is `0.75` and square root fo `0.75` is `~0.86`